Add plotly graphs dynamically
Say I have the following example that combines two Plotly graphs
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df = px.data.iris()

fig1 = px.line(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig1.update_traces(line=dict(color = 'rgba(50,50,50,0.2)'))

fig2 = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")

fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data)
fig3.show()

Say now I have not just two, but several plots I want to add dynamically and not type out explicitly as above. The following doesn't work, but does something similar exist where one doesn't have to explicitly type out the sum to add the graphs?
fig3 = go.Figure(data=sum([fig1.data, fig2.data]))   # this doesn't work


The us of + here is more like a tuple concatenation/append operator in this context. There's a few other ways to write this. Closest to what you were going for might be sum(zip(fig1.data, fig2.data), ())

@JNevill Thanks. I tried with r = [q.data, w.data, e.data]; go.Figure(sum(zip([i for i in r]), ())), but I still get an error. Is this not the generalization of what you did?

@JNevill I also tried with go.Figure(sum(tuple([i for i in r]), ())) but it also fails

Assuming r is a list of tuples of the figure data, then perhaps go.Figure(sum(zip(*r), ())) Although on second that that may screw with the order of the scatters if that is important.

If order is important than you could functools.reduce() and a lambda go.Figure(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, r))  or itertools.chain() like go.Figure(tuple(itertools.chain(*r)))

This can be handled with a simple function.
def dataSum(data):
    ret = data[0]
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        ret = ret + data[i]
    return ret

This works by adding values one by one, just like you do manually. In full context, that would be
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df = px.data.iris()

figs = []

fig1 = px.line(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig1.update_traces(line=dict(color = 'rgba(50,50,50,0.2)'))

figs.append(fig1.data)

fig2 = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")

figs.append(fig2.data)

fi3 = go.Figure(data=dataSum(figs))
fig3.show()

